# Yii 2 - radioList Template

Tags: php, yii2

I want to add template to radioList in yii2, which I tried, but I am unable to get the proper o/p.

The HTML is

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <label class="gender-head">Gender</label>
    <label class="signup-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="signup-gender" id="signupMale" checked  tabindex="3" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Male</span>
    </label>
    <label class="signup-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="signup-gender" id="signupFemale" tabindex="3" />
        <i></i>
        <span>Female</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

The o/p should look like this

[image]

The Yii2 code which I tried is...

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'gender', ['radioTemplate' => '<label class="gender-head">{label}</label><label class="signup-radio">{input}</label>'])->inline()->radioList([1 => 'Male', 0 => 'Female'], ['separator' => '', 'tabindex' => 3]); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

I have searched a lot on the template but did not get any proper response.

Comment: please inline your "expected output" image

Comment: I am unable to add image, as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: oh, that sucks... how about textual representation like `gender [ ] men [x] women [ ] other`

Comment: @qarma you could always edit the question to add the image :)

Comment: @JoeMiller Check here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#$radioTemplate-detail

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I finally got the way through which we can modify the input tag generation logic in Yii2

To get the above result of the radio buttons, I have developed the following code

```
            <div class="input-wrap">
                <div class="clearfix" id="UserLogin-gender">
                    <label class="radio-head">Gender</label>
                    <?=
                    $form->field($model, 'gender')
                        ->radioList(
                            [1 => 'Male', 0 => 'Female'],
                            [
                                'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

                                    $return = '<label class="modal-radio">';
                                    $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" tabindex="3">';
                                    $return .= '<i></i>';
                                    $return .= '<span>' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
                                    $return .= '</label>';

                                    return $return;
                                }
                            ]
                        )
                    ->label(false);
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="help-block"></div>
            </div>
```

The "item" option in the radioList is a callback function to the input generation logic written in Yii2. We can easily modify the layout of each element generated using this callback function and it's parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using the same approach for a long time. However I don't understand why you're initial approach wouldn't work. I've read the docs, it should work. It would be much more elegant solution. Have you been able to use your initial idea over time?

Comment: its working but fields are not checked after submission

Comment: i can not use other variable into   'item'

Comment: @VinodC yo need to pass the `$checked` param to the input as attribute

Answer (score 6):

maybe i'am too late but you can try this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'abc')->inline()->radioList(['example1' => 'example1', 'example2' => 'example2'])->label(false) ?>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425384/yii2-radio-inline-html-helper)

Comment: this will throw **Calling unknown method: yii\widgets\ActiveField::inline()**

Answer (score -2):

```
$form->field($model, 'gender')
     ->radioList(array(1 => 'Male', 0 =>'Female'), array('class' => 'i-checks'));
```

Comment: Why should OP use your code? Can you add some info about your answer?