# yii2 radio inline Html helper

Tags: php, yii2

I have this radioList in yii2

```
Html::radioList('abc',null,$new,['class' => 'form-control input-sm']);
```

It generates this:

```
<div class=radio>
```

but I want:

```
<div class=radio-inline>
```

please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let's say that `$new = [1 => 'Hello', 2 => 'World']`;

The generated output will be:

```
<div class="form-control input-sm">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="1"> Hello
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="2"> World
    </label>
</div>
```

If you want to add **radio** class to container tag you can do it like that:

```
echo Html::radioList('abc', null, $new, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm radio']);
```

For each input it will be:

```
echo Html::radioList('abc', null, $new, [
    'class' => 'form-control input-sm',
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'radio'],
]);
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#radioList%28%29-detail), it's pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you, but the genegated output is: 
<div class="form-control input-sm">
   <div class="radio"> 
   <label>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="1"> Hello
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio"> 
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="2"> World
    </label>
</div>
</div>

and i want change tag <div class=radio> to <div class="radio-inline">

Comment: I tested this right now and the output is exactly as I wrote in the question. Show the rest of the code, maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is proper solution

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'abc')->inline()->radioList(['example1' => 'example1', 'example2' => 'example2'])->label(false) ?>
```