# yii2 radioList inline formfield

Tags: php, css, forms, yii2

I have this radioList inline in Yii2:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'abc')->inline(true)->radioList(array('1'=>'yes',2=>'no')); ?>
```

It generated:

```
    <div class="form-group field-minstitution-abc">
         <label class="control-label" for="abc">Abc</label>
    <div>
   <div id="abc">
    <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="abc" value="1"> yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="2"> no
     </label>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But I want the label inline with the radio button like this:

[image]

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234684/yii-2-radiolist-template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the folowing code.

```
form->field($model, 'abc',
    ['wrapperOptions' => ['style' => 'display:inline-block']])
    ->inline(true)->radioList(array('1'=>'yes',2=>'no'));
```

The wrapper option is applied to the `div` tag with surrounds the radio buttons. The default display is `block`, causing the div to use al of the available space pushing the label up. The function `inline(true)` renders the radio buttons in one line.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `template` option of `field` method:

```
$form->field($model, 'abc', '<div class=\"radio\">\n{beginLabel}
{input}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{error}\n{hint}\n</div>')
->radioList(array('1'=>'yes',2=>'no')); ?>
```

Put any html what you want.